# How to append data to TensorFlow tfrecords file

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to append new data (e.g. pairs of images and labels) to an already existing tfrecord file?

The class [tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/lib/io/tf_record.py) does not seem to have any option for that.

This question may also be reformulated to how to concatenate tfrecord files.

Comment: Given [the TODO](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/lib/io/tf_record.py#L95), I'm guessing it's not supported yet. You could file a feature request on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the TODO, I opened a ticket: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7482

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the comments in the ticket I opened this won't be implemented, soon.