# Fast way to append field to examples in tensorflow tfrecords

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

What is a fast way to read tfrecords, add a field, and write them back out? Below is a program that does this, given a directory of `*.tfrecords`. Say doing this

```
                example = tf.train.Example()
                example.ParseFromString(rec_str.numpy())
                output_string = example.SerializeToString()
                writer.write(output_string)
```

for each record in the input is one unit of time, then adding

```
                    features = dict(example.features.feature.items())
                    features["pred"] = tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=prediction_output))
                    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=features))
```

before serializing and writing back is like 3 units of time.

It seems to add a lot - my tfrecords have like 50 scalar fields in them, I'm just adding one more, does anyone know of a more efficient way to do this? Below is a program. You can experiment with gzip compression, that didn't seem to make much difference for my files.

```
import os
import time
import glob
import logging
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def write_tfrecords_with_ap(input_dir, output_dir, write_zip, add_val, num_files):
    t0_all = time.time()
    tm_write = 0.0
    tm_feat_dict = 0.0

    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

    logging.info(f"Writing new tfrecords to {output_dir}")

    input_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(input_dir, "*.tfrecords"))[0:num_files]
    assert len(input_files)

    prediction_output = np.empty(shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32)

    num_records = 0
    for input_tfrec_file in input_files:
        print(f"input {input_tfrec_file}")
        t0_write = time.time()
        input_dset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(input_tfrec_file, compression_type="GZIP",)

        basename = os.path.basename(input_tfrec_file)
        output_tfrec_file = os.path.join(output_dir, basename)
        options = None
        if write_zip:
            options = tf.io.TFRecordOptions(compression_type="GZIP")
        with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(output_tfrec_file, options=options) as writer:
            for rec_str in input_dset:
                num_records += 1
                example = tf.train.Example()
                example.ParseFromString(rec_str.numpy())
                if add_val:
                    t0_feat_dict = time.time()
                    features = dict(example.features.feature.items())
                    tm_feat_dict += time.time() - t0_feat_dict
                    prediction_output[0] = 3.0
                    features["pred"] = tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=prediction_output))
                    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=features))
                output_string = example.SerializeToString()
                writer.write(output_string)
        print(f"out {output_tfrec_file}")

        tm_write += time.time() - t0_write
    tm_all = time.time() - t0_all
    print(
        f"Wrote {num_files} tfrecords files with {num_records} records. minutes: total={round(tm_all/60.0, 2)}  "
        f"writing={round(tm_write/60.0, 2)}  "
        f"feat_dict={round(tm_feat_dict/60.0, 2)}"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over the entire `Dataset` (= loading every sample into memory), and writing it back to disk again after appending your data is the fastest way to to it. As the IO is the most time consuming step, I don't think you'll gain much time by optimizing your code. You would need to append to the existing files, but you can't do that with `tfrecords`, and it won't be implemented any time soon: [How to append data to TensorFlow tfrecords file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125046/how-to-append-data-to-tensorflow-tfrecords-file).

Comment: I commented out the final `writer.write(output_str)` but that reduced speed from 2.27 minutes to 2.02 minutes. I have 163 features, it must be all the parsing, etc. I could try the json deserializing/serialzing, maybe thats faster

Comment: actually I don't see how to use json, I did some more timing, commenting out one line at a time, the most expensive line is `example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=features))` this takes .7 minutes, serializing that result to a string takes .4 mintes.